# Unexpected token when sending nested params to worker - Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Sidekiq worker to which I send my controller params. My controller params look like this.

```
def my_params
  params.require(:users).permit(employees: [:param1, param_requested_attributes: [:attribute]])
end
```

So when I send my JSON to the controller and check with byebug, params are correctly formatted, but when I send them to the worker like:

```
MyWorker.perform_async(my_params)
```

I iterate over each "employee" as:

```
my_params.each do |employee|
  data = JSON.parse(raw_data.gsub('=>', ':')) # to correctly format my json data
end
```

and I get an "unexpected token error" because 'params_requested_attributes' looks like:

```
"params_requested_attributes"=>[<ActionController::Parameters> {"attribute"=>"value"} permitted: true> ]
```

My question is, how can I avoid this "ActionController::parameters" when trying to JSON.parse my params? It only happens when I try to use these nested_attributes. I just want a raw json, but for some reason I get this "action controller params".

Comment: please include the raw params you are getting in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `my_params`:

```
def my_params
  params.require(:users).permit(...)
end
```

gives you an instance of `ActionController::Parameters` and the `params_requested_attributes` inside that is another instance of `ActionController::Parameters`. Then you enqueue a job with:

```
MyWorker.perform_async(my_params)
```

which has to serialize `my_params` into a database and that serialization isn't handling the inner `ActionController::Parameters` the way you want it to.

You could convert the parameters to a nested hash yourself:

```
MyWorker.perform_async(my_params.to_h)
```

to get rid of the the `ActionController::Parameters` and end up with plain hashes and arrays in your job.

If you really want JSON that your job manually unpacks then you'll have to massage `my_params` a little more. Perhaps you'd want to `my_params.to_h` and then JSON encode then nested `params_requested_attributes`. This sounds like a solution in search of a problem, I think passing `my_params.to_h` to the job is where you want to go.

Comment: This is it! Thank you. I actually got to a "sort of" solution already, but i'm just doing '.to_h' instead of '.to_unsafe_h'. I'm gonna be reading the difference between the two to know which one to use. Thank you!!

Comment: In this case it shouldn't matter if you use `#to_h` or `#to_unsafe_h`, I should have gone with `to_h` to be honest. Generally you'd use `to_unsafe_h` if you want to unpack `params` into a hash without any strong parameters stuff at all.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse` turns a json string into a ruby object. So if you need just the raw json string you should use `raw_data` and skip the `.gsub` call.
However I cannot see from your example how `raw_data` relates to the employee value.

Comment: Thanks Gerald, my problem actually appears when i send the params to the worker (for some reason it sends it as ) `"params_requested_attributes"=>[<ActionController::Parameters> {"attribute"=>"value"} permitted: true> ]` instead of `"params_requested_attributes"=>[{"attribute"=>"value"}]`